# Can GKE Gateway Controller work with a custom auth flow?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am looking for a straightforward way to setup GKE for a new project so that I can use less demanding nodes in a Google managed environment.

I have setup GKE in a previous example with Istio and its Ingress gateway. This works perfectly fine although I feel that I am overcomplicating things and I need to use N1 machines which are quite costly to start the project with. See documentation below.
https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/gke/

Now I was looking into the GKE Gateway controller. The thought process on how to use it, seemed quite nice, although, I am missing a bunch of stuff.

Now my question is, imagine that I want to use GKE Gateway controller instead of an Istio Ingress gateway. Can I manage the centralized auth flow like Istio offers with its RequestAuthentication and AuthorizationPolicy kinds
(https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-jwt/)
In the GKE Gateway controller?

Comment: API Gateway provides a variety of authentication techniques that are appropriate for various applications and scenarios. You can choose from [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authentication-method).

Comment: GKE gateway maybe currently in beta mode, but yes at least could support the basic auth, however I was looking into this doc there nothing much related to auth flow or auth, gateway could be useful for routing and managing traffic. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gateway-api#gateway_controller